# clarification on whats being executed in a boost::strand

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have a question regarding what is, and isn't, running in the `strand`. I've read posts on SO, as well as the documentation for `strand` but I want to make sure that I have understood it correctly in relation to the code below.

The class below is a `tcp` client which asynchronously sends stuff to someone who cares.

I also want to mention that `io_service::run` has been called on multiple `threads`.

```
int main( )
{ 
    /* Other stuff */
    client.WriteAsync( buffer1 ); 
    client.WriteAsync( buffer2 );
}


/* TcpClient class */

void TcpClient::WriteAsync( std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::streambuf> buffer )
{
    // 1
    _strand.post( [ this, buffer ]( ) 
    {
        _outbuffer.push( buffer );
        if ( _outbuffer.size( ) > 1 ) return;
        // 2
        Write( );
    } );
}

void TcpClient::Write( )
{       
    // 3
    boost::asio::async_write( _socket,
        *_outbuffer.front( ),
        // 4
        [ this ]( boost::system::error_code const& error,
            size_t const bytesTransferred )
    {               
        _outbuffer.pop( );          
        if ( error )
        {
            std::cout << "Error writing: " << error.message( ) << std::endl;
        }
        if ( !_outbuffer.empty( ) )
        {
            // 5
            Write( );
        }
    } );
}
```

**1:** `_strand.post` is called, if there is nothing currently running the `strand` will dispatch the passed in handler. In this case the `lambda` being passed to the strand will execute in the strand. If there is already work being done, the handler will be queued.

**2:** `Write`, when called from within the `lambda` passed to `post` is running in the `strand`

**3:** `async_write` is called within the `strand`. If `async_write` has not completed the `strand` will not have dispatched the next handler.

**4:** The `async_write` completion handler is **not** running in the `strand`. When the `async_write` completion handler is invoked the `strand` will pop the next unit of work off of its queue and dispatch it.

**5:** `Write` is called from within the `async_write` completion handler and is **not** running in the `strand`

I want to know if my above statements are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1: _strand.post is called, if there is nothing currently running the strand will dispatch the passed in handler. In this case the lambda being passed to the strand will execute in the strand. If there is already work being done, the handler will be queued.

Correct.

> 2: Write, when called from within the lambda passed to post is running in the strand

Correct.

> 3: async_write is called within the strand. If async_write has not completed the strand will not have dispatched the next handler.

Incorrect.  When the lambda passed to the strand "returns" the next queued bit of strand work is run.

> 4: The async_write completion handler is not running in the strand.

Correct

> When the async_write completion handler is invoked the strand will pop the next unit of work off of its queue and dispatch it.

Incorrect, again, when the lambda passed to the strand "returns" the next queued bit of strand work is run.

> 5: Write is called from within the async_write completion handler and is not running in the strand

Correct.

If you want the async_write completion handler to be run within the strand (which you most likely do because of the shared access to _outbuffer) you can use [bind_executor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/bind_executor.html).

e.g.

```
void TcpClient::Write( )
{       
    boost::asio::async_write( _socket,
        *_outbuffer.front( ),
        // here
        boost::asio::bind_executor(_strand, [ this ]( boost::system::error_code const& error, size_t const bytesTransferred )
    {               
        _outbuffer.pop( );          
        if ( error )
        {
            std::cout << "Error writing: " << error.message( ) << std::endl;
        }
        if ( !_outbuffer.empty( ) )
        {
            // 5
            Write( );
        }
    } ));
}
```

Comment: The reason I asked this question is because of the shared access to the `_outbuffer`. I was concerned.  Thanks your for reply